# Winrm error in while restarting the celeryd service

Tags: python, celery, winrm, celeryd

The module `winrm` is installed with all its dependencies, but still the `celeryd` service is not able to run. Here is the error trace:

```
worker1@man11idm01.stman00.isyntax.net: DOWN /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of cryptography will drop support for Python 2.6   DeprecationWarning Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 311, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 761, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 693, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 179, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 274, in
__call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 212, in run
    state_db=self.node_format(state_db, hostname), **kwargs   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 128, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 121, in import_default_modules
    tuple(maybe_list(self.app.conf.CELERY_INCLUDE))   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 103, in import_task_module
    return self.import_from_cwd(module)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 112, in import_from_cwd
    package=package,   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/contextlib.py", line 34, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 64, in cwd_in_path
    yield cwd   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 106, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)   File "/usr/lib/celery/phim_onsite/operate.py", line 14, in <module>
    from phim_onsite.transmit import tx_data, tx_pcm_discovery, tx_deployment_status   File "/usr/lib/celery/phim_onsite/transmit.py", line 19, in <module>
    from scanline.trinity import scanline_endpoints, scanline_scanner   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scanline/trinity.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scanline.product.isp import ISPProductScanner   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scanline/product/isp.py", line 17, in <module>
    from scanline.host.isp import ISPHostScanner   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scanline/host/isp.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scanline.utilities.win_rm import extract_credentials   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scanline/utilities/win_rm.py", line 2, in <module>
    import winrm ImportError: No module named winrm
Restarting node worker1@man11idm01.stman00.isyntax.net: * Child terminated with errorcode 255

FAILED
+ exit 0
```

Comment: This says you are using python 2.6 which you shouldn't be using.  Do you have a venv that hasn't been activated?

Comment: python 2.6 is for production env., so can't help on it now. There is no virtual environment here.